# Calling the dialog window based on the changes in form input fields

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I have a button called `Add` on clicking this button i am calling an component called `add-customer` inside the `dialog window` like this:

[image]

**Scenario:** If i made any changes in the `input fields` of the `add-customer` component and click `CANCEL` button one more `dialogue` will be called with an message like this:

[image]

**Here is the issue is:**

The `2nd dialog window` is coming **only if the changes made in required input fields and click CANCEL button** ,  but I want to call the `2nd dialog window` even **if i made changes in any of the input fields and checkbox.**

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-issue-d5ikgz?file=app/demo/demo.component.ts) demo.

Comment: Use `this.addCusForm.touched` instead of `this.addCusForm.dirty` in your `openDialog()` method.
Refer : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-issue-fazla6?file=app/add-customer/add-customer.component.ts
, But this will even open the pop-up if user has not interacted with any input fields also. See, if this is what you require, else some modifications can be made.

Comment: I have already tried with the `touch` proeprty, but the issue is by default the 1st inpu field is touched/selected.

Comment: Yes, i tried the same with `tabindex="-1"`, but it will work only for required fields.

Comment: Ya I gave `autoFocus: false,` in order to avoid focusing on 1st input field by default and used `touched` property still the same issue..:)

Comment: Then, either you have to use the `valueChanges` for every field in the form, or in `ngOnInit()` you can store the previous form value by getting each field, and on cancel click, check the form new values with the saved ones, and open dialog accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It must be pretty easy with `dirty` function. It returns `true` if any of changes has been made on form.

Ex :

```
if(this.addCusForm.dirty){
  //show modal
}
```

> Note : Do not forget to add the `formControlName` for each control.

Here is the working copy - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-issue-sgjc1f

Comment: If possible, please edit in my **stackblitz** example...:)

Comment: I had given the link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can subscribe to form valueChanges observable that will emit a value if any of form control value hase changes ,alsoe any form control elemnt has the same api so you can subscribe to from or specific control to check the changes

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.addCusForm.valueChanges.subscribe( value => {
 ...
 })

 this.addCusForm.get('firstname').valueChanges.subscribe( value => {
 ...
 })

}
```